# In MySQL database, how can I reach the rows

Tags: mysql, processmaker

| A header | Another header |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | **a**dc**xy** |
| 2 | **ax**se**y** |
| 3 | drfhgh |
| 4 | **a**y**x**ddf**y** |
| 5 | weaxjug |
| ... | ... |

In MySQL database, how can I reach bolded row with "axy" search?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck? Should this only cover rows where the letters appear in the given order, or in any order?

Answer (score 2):

Use `like` with the predicate built from the letters you're searching for:

```sql
select *
from mytable
where another_header like '%a%x%y%'
```

To do this in pure SQL (ie with a single parameter `'axy'`):

```sql
select *
from mytable
where another_header like regexp_replace($search, '(?<=.)|(?=.)', '%')
```

---

All your examples that match start with `a` and end with `y`, but it's not clear if that's a requirement. If it is, use `like 'a%x%y'` instead, which requires a slightly different regex:

```sql
select *
from mytable
where another_header like regexp_replace($search, '(?<=.)(?=.)', '%')
```

See [live demo of these regexp_replace](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/qdAdmQKDy5Q5kz8RmkhGVr/0).

Comment: thanks, But I want this SQL query in suggest field in Processmaker, that in this field, your text will be displayed as soon as you type.

Comment: According to these pictures: (https://s2.uupload.ir/files/untitled_lka8.png) and (https://s2.uupload.ir/files/untitled2_5u78.png)

Comment: @H.RSh See edits to answer - is that what you want?